# How to ignore FileField data if its empty in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am new to Django and trying to learn more but can't find a solution
I want to make Django ignore the form if the form is empty and only change other text input
It is an editor to edit info and when it opens it fills info automatically and if you want u can add a word or leave as is a problem is to I have to select an image every time how can I make Django ignore that input?
here is code

**forms.py**:

```py
    picture = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'file-input'}), required=False ),
    profile_info = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textarea'}), max_length=260, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('picture','profile_info')
```

**views.py**:

```py
def EditProfile(request):
    user = request.user.id
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user__id=user)
    BASE_WIDTH = 400
    # self.objects.exclude(file__isnull=True) i am tryng to put this code but dont works?

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            profile.picture = form.cleaned_data.get('picture')
            profile.profile_info = form.cleaned_data.get('profile_info')
            profile.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm()

    context = {
        'form':form,
    }

    return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', context)
```

Please, someone, guide me on how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        if not request.FILES.get('picture'):
            // do something
            
        else:

           profile.picture = form.cleaned_data.get('picture')
           profile.profile_info = form.cleaned_data.get('profile_info')
           profile.save()
```

Comment: which part i shoud put?

Comment: it works thanks i learn what details doing and now i know thanks